# Mac full size keyboards with built in trackpad

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, trackpad

I want to attach a full size keyboard to my macbook for at least a couple of reasons:

a) the macbook keyboard is slightly undersized.  It is enough so to give my fingers headaches (or something like that..)

b) I want to look straightforward at the screen but not use an external monitor. Thus I would position the keyboard 12 inches below a small pedestal for the mac

Having looked at numerous sites I can not find a full size keyboard with trackpad. There are very few options for keyboard with trackpad for Mac to choose from. Do any exist?

Comment: Do you want the trackpad off to the right of the keys or in front of the keys?  I've seen them both ways and you might have to settle for a keyboard that's designated as a Windows keyboard however they typically work on a Mac as well.  I sometimes use my Dell full-sized keyboard on my MBP and it works without any issues.

Comment: @user3439894  Please make this an answer so I can award. In addition I would like to follow up on this: did you have to do any special drivers and were there complications with mapping keys to their mac counterparts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want the trackpad off to the right of the keys or in front of the keys? I've seen them both ways and you might have to settle for a keyboard that's designated as a Windows keyboard however they typically work on a Mac as well. I sometimes use my Dell full-sized keyboard on my MBP and it works without any issues.

To answer your follow up question, no special drivers were necessary.  OS X just wanted a couple of keys presses, it will tell you which ones, and then it set it up.  The mappings were basically the same although the names of the Command key and Windows key are different it functions as the Command key on OS X.

Comment: trackpad below is better, but i would prefer not to sacrifice full size keys for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can buy a wired Mac full size keyboard and a Magic Trackpad. Both are manufactured by Apple. Check Apple Store.

Comment: I am looking for combination keypad plus trackpad on same keyboard